# Makefile.PL meta.json prereqs for OS so module won't be installed on Windows

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm working on a Perl Module which won't run on Windows, to prevent CPAN Testers failing it on Windows I want to use the meta files in the distribution generated from the Makefile to prevent the module from being installed or tested on Windows.

If the situation were the opposite (module only works on Windows) specifying a dependency on Win32 would make it installable on Windows only.

Also if the module is converted to Dist::Zilla, need a corresponding dist.ini solution.

Comment: Win32.pm simply has `unless ($^O eq "MSWin32" || $^O eq "cygwin") { die "OS unsupported\n"; }` in its Makefile.PL.You could use the same approach (just flipping the condition).

Comment: Two failings, all this solution does is make the install fail on the unsupported platform, it does not get included in the meta yml/json files. It is a fault of the specs for those that there is no specific key for supported platforms. The other failing is the solution doesn't port to Dist::Zilla if the distribution switches to it.

Comment: I just found Devel::AssertOS and Dist::Zilla::Plugin::AssertOS which would address the portability.

Comment: Re "*it does not get included in the meta yml/json files*", It doesn't even get to the point where those are generated!

Comment: Re "*I just found Devel::AssertOS and Dist::Zilla::Plugin::AssertOS which would address the portability.*", Not at all. They can't possibly do anything different. Devel::AssertOS doesn't even have anything to do with module installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CPAN Testers FAQ](http://cpanwiki.grango.org/wiki/CPANAuthorNotes) says:

> While it isn't a very elegant solution, the recommend approach is to either die in the Makefile.PL or Build.PL (or BAIL_OUT in a test file) with one of the following messages:

> No support for OS

> OS unsupported

Comment: Using Devel::AssertOS to tell the Makefile when to die looks better to me than finding conditions for specific OSes to use in the Makefile. Because Dist::Zilla has a plugin for it the same codes 'use Devel::AssertOS qw( -MSWin32 -Cigwin);'  can be copied into dist.ini. Unless you see a downside or have a better recommendation please add to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Devel::AssertOS is very, very simple. Look at the code and decide if you want to have another dependency just for that. I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: You're right about that, but it's still valuable as a reference guide for the OS identification strings needed. The Dist::Zilla plugin bundles a copy of it into your distribution and flags it to not be indexed on cpan.

Comment: historically, bundling other software in your distro has other problems. You are stuck with whatever you send out, and if there's a problem with that, you have to update your software despite not actually changing anything the user cares about.  You might read about the history of Module::Install, which no one really uses anymore. You're taking on a lot of complexity there for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to add a dependency on [Platform::Unix](https://metacpan.org/pod/Platform::Unix) or [Platform::Windows](https://metacpan.org/pod/Platform::Windows).

This has the advantage that when your module is uploaded to CPAN, people will see "Platform::Whatever" in the dependencies, so it's immediately obvious what platform your module requires.

[More information on Platform::*](https://metacpan.org/pod/Platform).